# AS3 down shooting game

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

Im programing a simple game for school project. It's something like Space Invaders, but I cant insert more than one enemy at time... It just shows me one enemy and now I'm getting an error that says "Property x not found on String and there is no default value."

I've tried to create a vector to create multiple enemies but it's not working at all...

Here is my code:

Variables for the enemies:

```
private var bird_1:MovieClip;
    private var InimigoList:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
    private var NumInimigos:int = 10;
    private var birdVelo:Number = 3;
```

And then:

```
bird_1 = new MovieClip( textureAtlas.getTextures("bird"), 5 );
        bird_1.smoothing = "none";
        Starling.juggler.add(bird_1);
        bird_1.visible = false;
        addChild(bird_1);

        for (var i:uint = 0; i < NumInimigos; i++) {
        var Enemy:MovieClip = new MovieClip (textureAtlas.getTextures("bird"),12);
        Enemy.smoothing = "none";
        Enemy.visible = false;
        Enemy.x = i * 50 + Enemy.width;
        InimigoList.push(Enemy);
        Starling.juggler.add(Enemy);
        addChild(Enemy);
```

Now I want multiple enemies to show up on the stage. Then I've done this:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < NumInimigos; i++) {
            var newEnemy = InimigoList[i];
            newEnemy += birdVelo;
            if (newEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth){
            newEnemy.x = 0;
            }
            }
```

But it's not working... I get just one enemy and no more... Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: I think your problem is 'newEnemy += birdVelo;' should be 'newEnemy.x += birdVelo;'

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating invisible enemies?

```
Enemy.visible = false;
```

Are you putting all enemies on the same area of the stage?

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < NumInimigos; i++) {
            var newEnemy = InimigoList[i];
            newEnemy += birdVelo;
            if (newEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth){
            newEnemy.x = 0;
            }
            }
```

What does this do?

```
newEnemy += birdVelo;
```

Have you tried directly referencing the object from its Array position?

```
InimigoList[i].x = newx;
InimigoList[i].y = mewy;
```